# Html form posting, no data passed on

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I've been sitting with this problem for a while now, can't seem to figure out whats wrong with  the code.

The problem is that no data gets posted from the form to the script.

```
<div class="mws-panel-body">
    <form class="mws-form" action="blueprints/add" method="post" id="pForm">
        <div class="mws-form-inline">
            <div class="mws-form-row">
                <label>Blueprint name</label>
                <div class="mws-form-item small">
                    <input type="text" class="mws-autocomplete mws-textinput" id="pName" value="" />
                    <div>The name of the blueprint, search completion is enabled.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mws-form-row">
                <label>Hangar</label>
                <div class="mws-form-item micro">
                    <select id="pHangar">
                        <option value="0" selected>Personal</option>
                        <option value="1">Corporation</option>
                    </select>
                    <div>Indicates who the blueprint belongs to.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mws-form-row">
                <label>State</label>
                <div class="mws-form-item micro">
                    <select id="pState">
                        <option value="1" selected>Original</option>
                        <option value="0">Copy</option>
                    </select>
                    <div>The state of the blueprint, be it original or a copy.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mws-form-row">
                <label>Productions runs</label>
                <div class="mws-form-item small">
                    <input type="text" class="mws-textinput" id="pRuns" value="0" />
                    <div>The number of production runs left on copy.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mws-form-row">
                <label>Material efficiency</label>
                <div class="mws-form-item small">
                    <input type="text" class="mws-textinput" id="pME" value="0" />
                    <div>The current material efficiency level of the blueprint.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mws-form-row">
                <label>Production efficiency</label>
                <div class="mws-form-item small">
                    <input type="text" class="mws-textinput" id="pPE" value="0" />
                    <div>The current production efficiency level of the blueprint.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mws-button-row">
            <input type="submit" value="Add blueprint" class="mws-button blue" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="mws-button gray" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

It seems to be a problem with the form itself, as if the form is set to get, it just enters the script with a question-mark only, `blueprints/add?`, meaning no data gets passed on at all.

Any pointers or suggestions will be appreciated.

My platform is PHP if that helps.

Comment: The request runs through a modrewrite condition, rewriting it to a PHP page

Comment: Wow i feel silly, completely forgot that! How could that happen :|
Post it as an answer please.

Comment: Might be because i recently went from JS post to html post.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be using the name attribute of input to send the data to a PHP post script. Example:

Form:

```
<form action="add.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" />
</form>
```

Script (add.php):

```
<?php
//print the $_POST['firstname'] variable
echo $_POST['firstname'];
?>
```

Comment: Never knew this. Is this how HTML forms work?

Answer (score 7):

You need to add the name attribute to your input and select elements

```
<input type="text" name="myinput">
```

Php will then build your $_POST array with those names.