# How can I post data to backend using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm quite new to all this and was wondering if you could help shed some light on this. I have a datepicker widget in a form in my html and a javascript code which responds to change in date picker. What I want is when the user changes the date in the date picker widget, to post the changes to my Django backend

The html snippet is

```
<form id="availability_form" method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-sx-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group date" data-provider="datepicker">
            <input class="form-control" id="id_availableDate">
            <div class="input-group-addon btn">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the javascript snippet is:

```
...
... 
$('#id_availableDate').change(
    function () {
        $("#availability_form").submit();
    }
);
```

This tends to work, I see that the data is posted and my Django view receives a post, but when I examine the contents I don't see any data from the datepicker sent. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you just miss the name attribute in the input in html. The post array will have a key that is the name of the field and the value will be the value of your input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html form posting, no data passed on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791132/html-form-posting-no-data-passed-on)

Comment: @LelioFaieta and James Thorpe thank you both for your answers. Yes it is working now. Kudos to both of you. Much appreciated :D

Comment: @FrancisN Glad that helped. Then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the name of the field:

```
<form id="availability_form" method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-sx-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group date" data-provider="datepicker">
            <input class="form-control" id="id_availableDate" name="availableDate">
            <div class="input-group-addon btn">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and you can get to the value as `$_POST['availableDate'];`